# Editing a text file specific line

Tags: python-3.x

I am creating a maths quiz and need to add scores to a login sheet. The text file line looks like this: Name , Username, Password

I was wondering if you are able to edit the line so it looks like this: Name , Username, Password, Attempt1 = 12

Name , Username, Password, Attempt1 = 12, Attempt2 = 23 and so on

Thanks for the help Adam

By the way this is how I find the line:

```
 lookup = Name   
 with open("users.txt") as myFile:
    for num, line1 in enumerate(myFile, 1):
        if lookup in line1:
            line = line1
```

Comment: Make yourself familiar with dictionaries and the json library and this task will be much easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, the problem is not specific to Python. A text file (in principle) is read into memory first, then you modify the memory content, and write it back.

There is a possibility to seek to certain position in the file and write a content there, but it would bring more problems in your case.

The first thing you need to solve is whether the file can be accessed by more users simultaneously. If yes, imagine the situation when two users want to read-modify-write back. One of the values may "disappear". This is true for any file, including the recommended `.json` solutions.

I suggest to introduce another layer in your application--to wrap modification of the values in an object (or function)--that would hide how exactly it is done. Later, you can modify this implementation to use JSON, or a database, or whatever.

If more users can access the data simultaneously, then the simple solution would be to use a directory with separate text file for each user (a kind of simple database).

Answer (score 0):

Although this might not be an answer I'm posting it anyway. Disregard if this doesn't fit your needs. Merely an example of my comment.

Here is an alternative way to store information.
Think of a dictionary that all the keys are the usernames:

usernames.json

```
{
    "johnny": {
        "name": "John Doe",
        "password": "123",
        "attempts": [
            12,
            23
        ]
    },
    "foo": {
        "name": "Bar",
        "password": "345",
        "attempts": []
    }
}
```

You can then load the data with a script (script.py)

```
import json

with open("usernames.json") as f:
    mydict = json.load(f)
```

Read data:

```
print(mydict.keys()) # prints ["johnny","foo"]
print(mydict["johnny"]["attempts"]) #prints [12,23]
```

And add data:

```
mydict["newuser"] = {"name":"hello","password":891,"attempts":[]} #adds new user
mydict["johnny"]["attempts"].append(15) # adds new attempt
```

And dump it back to a dict:

```
with open('usernames.json', 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(mydict, outfile, indent=4)
```